# Why can't I specify the width and height of a cell in an HTML table?

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

I am using CSS,  but for the sake of quick testing I'm just using an inline style. This is the code I am trying to implement:

```
echo "<td style='height=10px; width=10px;'>";
```

it makes sure that the max width of the cell is 10px ,  however the height overflows with the text so and it get very large (high).

what I am trying to achieve is any information that is in that cell more than 30 characters I want to hide so you can't see it.

(I know 30 characters is more than 10px but I am just playing to see if it worked!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong:

Bad

```
echo "<td style='height=10px; width=10px;'>";
```

Good

```
echo "<td style='height:10px; width:10px;'>";
```

However, this doesn't fix the problem. The way I read the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html), only fixed layout tables are allowed to clip their content on overflow (versus resizing to accommodate it).

A better/simpler way would be to use a `DIV`.

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Aa4JL/

However, if your data is tabular and you need to use a table, you can achieve the same effect by wrapping the cell's contents in a `DIV`.

```
<table>
    <tr>
     <td><div style='height:10px; width:10px; overflow: hidden;'>This text is clipped.</div></td>         
    </tr>
</table>​
```

Note that if you don't care about clipping based on height you can achieve a nice ellipses effect using fixed layout tables combined with `white-space: nowrap` combined with `text-overflow: ellipsis`. This does not require wrapping the content with a DIV. Note that the ellipsis effect will only work in newer browsers (content should still be clipped in older browsers).

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed;width:50px;">
    <tr>
     <td style='width:50px; overflow: hidden; white-space:nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;'>Long string of text with nice ellipses effect.</td>         
    </tr>
</table>
```

This fiddle has all the techniques I've just described: http://jsfiddle.net/Aa4JL/4/

Answer (score 3):

You can use text-overflow. [This](http://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis) is an example of using `text-overflow:ellipsis`. I created an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aa4JL/5/) by just copying the code from said example.

Answer (score 1):

i think you cant do it..
html only define the base size of the cell which means what size will the cell be  if you dont have any text. if your text is larger then the cell it wont stop it.

a better way to do what you're trying to do is to use php and the substring() function..

let me know if it helps or if you need help with that

Comment: ah ok. thank you, I will use php to limit its size.. thank you.. thats annoying that we cant though!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work if you wrap the `td` contents in a `div`:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LUmNc/

Answer (score 0):

the html attributes should also be defined in double quotes, such as

```
echo "<td style=\"height:10px; width:10px;\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
td {
    overflow-x: hidden;

}
</style>
```